# How to change the format of date in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, string, string-formatting

I have two textboxes: `TextBox1`, `TextBox2`, and a button `Button1`.
I want to insert a random date into `TextBox1` (format -- dd/mm/yyyy)  and after clicking the button I want to convert the inserted date into different format (yyyy/mm/dd).

How do I get this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To parse the date that was set into the first `TextBox`:

```
var parsedDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(
    textBox1.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

To set the same date to the second `TextBox`, but in different format:

```
var textBox2.Text = parsedDateTime.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

**[Edit]** As was found out the format is not `dd/MM/yyyy`, it is `d/M/yyyy`:

```
var textBox1 = new TextBox { Text = "2/3/2004" };
var parsedDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(textBox1.Text, "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var textBox2 = new TextBox();
textBox2.Text = parsedDateTime.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

Comment: @Bijay Ojha - what error did you get and on which line of code?

Comment: thanks Alex for reply. but i am still getting the same problem. the error is something lie this"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"  in the second line where where you declare textbox 2 , i think we can't declare var before that..

Comment: @ Alex Aza "var parsedDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(TextBox1.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);"----this application built successfully but i run this application it showing a error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." .

Comment: @Bijay Ojha - can you show what exactly is the string that you are parsing?

Comment: @Bijay Ojha - I assume that the date is not in the format `dd/mm/yyyy`, as you specified in the question. I don't see other reasons.

Comment: "2/3/2004" as in foramt "dd/MM/yyyy"

Comment: @Alex Aza yes i got it ...thanks ...i should pass "02/03/2004" instead of that i used to pass"2/3/2004"..thank a lot...

Comment: @Bijay Ojha - so the format is `d/M/yyyy`, not `dd/MM/yyyy`. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Documented nicely on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Comment: my question is not that , i want to insert a random date in some datetime format and i want the result in different datetime format after clicking the button...in that example it predefined the date but i want to insert any random date...